# node script just stops

Tags: node.js, linux

I have a very large multi section script with a LOT of loops and some recursion in it.  When I run it on a Very Large dataset, the script will simply stop running.  It stops with a 0 exit code.  It VERY clearly does not actually finish running...it just...stops.

```
asyncLib.waterfall([
   getPronghornToken,
   saveSchedulers,
   saveServices,
   populateServRefs,
   saveServiceGroups,
   saveNetworks,
   populateNetRefs,      //never actually gets out of this function.  Just exits with code 0
   saveNetworkGroups,
   saveRuleGroups,
   fetchRuleGroupIds,
   populateRules,
   saveRules,
   getPolicyId,
   linkRuleGroup
], function (err, result) {
   if (err){
       console.error("Something bad happened. Please try again");
       process.exit(1);
   }
   console.log("done");
});
```

What I'm looking for:  **Why would a script just stop mid loop and exit with a 0 code?**

Note: Alternate code.

```
getPronghornToken((err, token) => {
if(err) {
    console.log("Error occured getPronghornToken");
    throw err;
}
   saveSchedulers(token, (err, token) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error occured saveSchedulers");
        throw err;
    }
    saveServices(token, (err, token) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error occured saveServices");
            throw err;
        }
        populateServRefs(token, (err, token) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error occured populateServRefs");
                throw err;
            }
            saveServiceGroups(token, (err, token) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Error occured saveServiceGroups");
                    throw err;
                }
                saveNetworks(token, (err, token) => {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("Error occured saveNetworks");
                        throw err;
                    }
                    populateNetRefs(token, (err, token) => {
                        if(err) {
                            console.log("Error occured populateNetRefs");
                            throw err;
                        }
                        saveNetworkGroups(token, (err, token) => {
                            if(err) {
                                console.log("Error occured saveNetworkGroups");
                                throw err;
                            }
                            saveRuleGroups(token, (err, token) => {
                                if(err) {
                                    console.log("Error occured saveRuleGroups");
                                    throw err;
                                }
                                fetchRuleGroupIds(token, (err, token) => {
                                    if(err) {
                                        console.log("Error occured fetchRuleGroupIds");
                                        throw err;
                                    }
                                    populateRules(token, (err, token) => {
                                        if(err) {
                                            console.log("Error occured populateRules");
                                            throw err;
                                        }
                                        saveRules(token, (err, token) => {
                                            if(err) {
                                                console.log("Error occured saveRules");
                                                throw err;
                                            }
                                            getPolicyId(token, (err, token) => {
                                                if(err) {
                                                    console.log("Error occured getPolicyId");
                                                    throw err;
                                                }
                                                linkRuleGroup(token, (err, token) => {
                                                    if(err) {
                                                        console.log("Error occured linkRuleGroup");
                                                        throw err;
                                                    }

                                                    console.log("Successfully installed all files");
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
   });
});
```

No errors thrown.  Does NOT print out the innermost message.  Callback pattern verified.

Last Function running looks like this:

```
async function populateNetRefs(token, callback) {
//let newNetRefs = [];
for(let index = 0; index < networkGroups.length; index++) {
    if (index >= networkGroups.length) {
        console.log("Net Refs Finished")
        return callback(null, token);
    }
    let networkGroup = networkGroups[index];
    try {
        console.log(`fetching network number: ${index+1} / ${networkGroups.length}`);
        let newNetRefs = await fetchNetId(token, networkGroup._netRefs);

        networkGroup._netRefs = newNetRefs;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`An error occurrent fetching the network id for index ${index+1} / ${networkGroups.length}: ${err}`);
    }
}
}
```

The Inner Function:

```
function fetchNetId(token, _netRefs) {
let fetchFinished = 0;
let newNetRefs = [];
let errCount = 1;
console.log("ZZ Fetchid Start ZZ");
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _netRefs.forEach(function(_netRef) {
        let options = {
            //Required to be hidden
        };

        let req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            let reply = [];
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                console.log("YY GET DATA CHUNK YY");
                reply.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                fetchFinished++;
                console.log("Reply is : " + reply.join());
                //There is some logic in this spot.  Not for you.
                console.log("fetchFinished is: " + fetchFinished + ", size is: " + _netRefs.length);
                if (fetchFinished === _netRefs.length) {
                    resolve(newNetRefs);
                }
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(`problem with request ${errCount++}: ${e.message}`);
            //reject(e);
        });

        let body = JSON.stringify({
            "options" : {
                "start": 0,
                "limit": 5,
                "sort": {

                },
                "filter": {
                    "name":{"$eq":_netRef}
                }
            }
        });
        console.log("XX Sending Request XX");
        req.write(body);
        req.end();
    });
});
}
```

**BEHAVIOR UPDATE - More Console Logs**

Here's the end of the console log:

```
fetching network number: 49 / 711
ZZ Fetchid Start ZZ
XX Sending Request XX
XX Sending Request XX
YY GET DATA CHUNK YY
Reply is : {hidden from you}
TroubleShootingDias: some guid
fetchFinished is: 1, size is: 2
YY GET DATA CHUNK YY
Reply is : {hidden from you}
TroubleShootingDias: some guid
fetchFinished is: 2, size is: 2
fetch success
fetching network number: 50 / 711
ZZ Fetchid Start ZZ
[vagrant@vag-host1 space-parser]$
```

Comment: You have an async function that takes a callback.

Comment: That's not illegal.  It might not be best practice....but the function runs just fine.  What you aren't seeing is that this is the 5th iteration of the function, the original was NOT async.  The problem has not changed.  even though the code and calling methods have....slightly....

Comment: The usual way of tracking down a problem like this is to insert `console.log()` statement in the code to figure out where exactly it's pooping out and then when you isolate the actual function causing the problem, you can insert more detailed logging or breakpoints and examine in detail.  You can save some time by using a binary search type algorithm for inserting log statements to progressively zero in on where it's failing. Since you don't show us your real code here, we can't even look at the code for problems.  Not sure what else we can do here.

Comment: as far as I can tell from the log statements I DO i have in place:  The loop wraps around to index 50, the function is awaited....and then the script stops and exits.  The await function doesn't appear to actually be running...it just....stops.  Also...IP reasons...I probably already posted too much, but I can't go any deeper.

Comment: I feel dumb.  If the _netRefs is empty, then the promise never returns.  I added an empty check and it worked immediately.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual solution to the problem:  If the array is empty, then the promise never resolves.  Added an empty check to the very top, before the loop.

```
function fetchNetId(token, _netRefs) {
let fetchFinished = 0;
let newNetRefs = [];
let errCount = 1;
console.log("ZZ Fetchid Start ZZ");
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

if(_netRefs.length === 0) return resolve([]) // <==============

_netRefs.forEach(function(_netRef) {
    let options = {
        //Required to be hidden
    };

    let req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let reply = [];
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log("YY GET DATA CHUNK YY");
            reply.push(chunk);
        });
//........
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you look at [async.waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall) to help structure code like this as it can be a mare to debug and read. A lot to grasp in your code above, but it could be helpful to wrap the following in a `try catch`. While you are handling req errors - those are only request errors and there may be something else including possible malformed url etc that will throw and you don't have the promise returning in this instance.

```
try {
    let req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let reply = [];
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log("YY GET DATA CHUNK YY");
            reply.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            fetchFinished++;
            console.log("Reply is : " + reply.join());
            //There is some logic in this spot.  Not for you.
            console.log("fetchFinished is: " + fetchFinished + ", size is: " + _netRefs.length);
            if (fetchFinished === _netRefs.length) {
                resolve(newNetRefs);
            }
        });
    });
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`problem with request ${errCount++}: ${err.message}`);
        return reject(err);
    });
}
catch(err) {
    console.error(`problem with request ${err.message}`);
    return reject(err);
}
```